# Terrafom create environment fully before destroying

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm now deploying my prod env in GCP using terraform,
each module has `create_before_destroy=true` and `provisioner`.
I'm using `provisioner` so the previews module state wont get deleted before I finish manual checks on the newly created state, and when I finish checking that everything is working well I'm providing the necessary input and the old state gets deleted.

I was wondering if there is a way to first create the entire env (just with `terraform apply` and not module by module) without configuring provisioner in each module, and then wait for a single input before deleting the old state, setting some kind of a "global" setting that first creates everything and after a specific input delete the old state  or some kind of a wrapper that provide that functionality.